# Most Pythonic Way to Build Dictionary From Single List

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of day names (typically Monday-Saturday, though special cases apply) that I want to create a dictionary out of. I want to initialize the value of each day to zero.

If I had a list of zeroes the same length of the list of days, this would be a simple use case of `zip()`. However, a list of zeroes is a waste of space, and if that were the only solution I'd just as soon do something like:

```
for day in weekList:
    dayDict[day] = 0
```

Is there a more pythonic way?

Comment: You might also want to look into a `collections.defaultdict(int)` -- This would do basically the same thing, but you won't get a `KeyError` if you try to get a key that doesn't exist.

Comment: Also see [dict.fromkeys all point to same list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516413/dict-fromkeys-all-point-to-same-list)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Apart from `dict.fromkeys` you can also use `dict-comprehension`, 
but  `fromkeys()` is faster than dict comprehensions:

```
In [27]: lis = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

In [28]: dic = {x: 0 for x in lis}

In [29]: dic
Out[29]: {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0}
```

For 2.6 and earlier:

```
In [30]: dic = dict((x, 0) for x in lis)

In [31]: dic
Out[31]: {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0}
```

`timeit` comparisons:

```
In [38]: %timeit dict.fromkeys(xrange(10000), 0)         # winner
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.4 ms per loop

In [39]: %timeit {x: 0 for x in xrange(10000)}
100 loops, best of 3: 2.08 ms per loop

In [40]: %timeit dict((x, 0) for x in xrange(10000))
100 loops, best of 3: 4.63 ms per loop
```

As mentioned in comments by @Eumiro and @mgilson it is important to note that `fromkeys()` and `dict-comprehensions` may return different objects if the values used are mutable objects:

```
In [42]: dic = dict.fromkeys(lis, [])

In [43]: [id(x) for x in dic.values()]
Out[43]: [165420716, 165420716, 165420716, 165420716] # all point to a same object

In [44]: dic = {x: [] for x in lis}

In [45]: [id(x) for x in dic.values()]
Out[45]: [165420780, 165420940, 163062700, 163948812]  # unique objects
```

Comment: Note that `.fromkeys()` is a lot faster.

Comment: While you can use the dict comprehension with default value being a list or anything else, `.fromkeys()` can be used for immutable objects only (None, bool, ints, floats, strings and tuples)

Comment: @eumiro -- Can you elaborate on this comment?  `dict.fromkeys(range(10),[])` works OK (of course, you're storing multiple references to *the same list* if that's what you're talking about), but that may be OK or even desireable in some cases.

Comment: @mgilson - I was speaking exactly about that case. It is important to mention, that dict comprehension and `.fromkeys()` do not return the same data structure (which will be probably ignored by inexperienced user).

Answer (score 25):

Use the [`.fromkeys()` class method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys):

```
dayDict = dict.fromkeys(weekList, 0)
```

It builds a dictionary using the elements from the first argument (a sequence) as the keys, and the second argument (which defaults to `None`) as the value for all entries.

By it's very nature, this method will reuse the value for all keys; don't pass it a mutable value such as a list or dict and expect it to create separate copies of that mutable value for each key. In that case, use a dict comprehension instead:

```
dayDict = {d: [] for d in weekList}
```