# Strange Output When Iterating Over a Dict of Lists

Tags: python

In a class Week, I have created a dictionary using the .fromkey() method that contains a string key for Monday-Saturday and initializes them all to an empty list:

```
self.weekDict = dict.fromkeys(dayNameList, [])
```

I have a function that then iterates over a list of employees, and, within each iteration, iterates over their work days and appends an employee to the corresponding weekDict list of each day:

```
def setWeekDict(employees):
            for employee in employees:
                for day in employees[employee].workDays:
                    self.weekDict[day].append(employee)
                    print "employee: " + employee
                    print "weekday/list: " + str(day) + str(self.weekDict[day])
```

I expect the weekDict lists to reflect everyone who is scheduled to work on a given day. Instead, it appears that the list for each day accumulates the total number of times I've iterated over each day for the employee. My print statements output this:

```
employee: Addison
weekday/list: Saturday['Addison']
employee: Addison
weekday/list: Monday['Addison', 'Addison']
employee: Addison
weekday/list: Tuesday['Addison', 'Addison', 'Addison']
employee: Addison
weekday/list: Wednesday['Addison', 'Addison', 'Addison', 'Addison']
employee: Addison
weekday/list: Thursday['Addison', 'Addison', 'Addison', 'Addison', 'Addison']
```

Obviously I only want 'Addison' or any other employee to appear once per day, and I can't understand what in my for loop would be contributing to each list adding the employee name + the amount of times the employee name has been added to other lists before. I can only think that dict.fromkeys() creates keys that actually all point to the same list, but I didn't think that was how the fromkeys() function worked.

Comment: You didn't read my answer carefully : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14259052/846892

Comment: Haha, you must have updated it since I last saw the post. Thanks. So fromkeys() only copies a reference when a mutable object is used -- good to know!

Comment: @user1427661 exactly, it copies the same object over and over.

Comment: @user1427661: `fromkeys()` only uses the same object even if an immutable object is used.  It's simply that you can't get yourself into as much trouble that way because the object is immutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fromkeys()` if used with mutable objects can lead to such behavior because it assigns the same object(same `id()`) to every key of the dictionary.

```
In [16]: dic=dict.fromkeys("spam",[])

In [17]: [id(x) for x in dic.values()]    #all of them are same objects
Out[17]: [141885196, 141885196, 141885196, 141885196]

In [18]: dic['s'].append(1)   #changing one changes others as well

In [19]: dic
Out[19]: {'a': [1], 'm': [1], 'p': [1], 's': [1]}
```

So, `dict-comprehensions` must be used with mutable objects:

```
In [20]: dic={x:[] for x in "spam"}

In [21]: [id(x) for x in dic.values()]               #unique objects
Out[21]: [141884972, 141848300, 142262988, 141895980]

In [22]: dic['s'].append(1)

In [23]: dic
Out[23]: {'a': [], 'm': [], 'p': [], 's': [1]}
```

Comment: If you need to support Python 2.6 or before, note that dictionary comprehensions were [added in 2.7](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/). You could make a similar generator expression and pass it to the `dict` constructor - `dic = dict((x, []) for x in dayNameList)` or use a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) (added in 2.5) - `from collections import defaultdic; dic = defaultdict(list)`.