# dict.fromkeys all point to same list

Tags: python

This was causing me a bit of grief...

I created a dictionary from a list

```
l = ['a','b','c']
d = dict.fromkeys(l, [0,0]) # initializing dictionary with [0,0] as values

d['a'] is d['b'] # returns True
```

How can I make each value of the dictionary a seperate list?  Is this possible without iterating over all keys and setting them equal to a list?  I'd like to modify one list without changing all the others.