# python- How does list([0,0]) differ from [0,0]?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I ran into a problem as described in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516413/dict-fromkeys-all-point-to-same-list). While using the dict comprehension I typed

```
keys = [x for x in range(21)]
value = [0,0]
dict1 = {key: value for key in keys}
```

instead of:

```
keys = [x for x in range(21)]
value = [0,0]
dict1 = {key: list(value) for key in keys}
```

In the former case, the problem remains. All the key values point to the same list. Why does this happen? In essence, what I don't understand is how does list([0,0]) not create a list as [[0,0]]?

EDIT: I understand that list(arg) takes only 1 argument. But what does it mean to run list over a list?

Comment: `list([0,0])` doesn't create `[[0,0]]` for the same reason that `list(0)` doesn't create `[0]`. That's just not what `list` does.

Comment: I understand that, however why doesn't dict1 = {key: value for key in keys} work?

Comment: `dict1 = {key: [0,0] for key in keys}`   solve the problem  in a more transparent way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have:

```
a = [0, 0]
b = list([0, 0])
```

Both `a` and `b` are lists containing the same values. But they're both unique instances of `list`.

Now, if you do:

```
c = a
d = b
```

`c` points to the same instance of `a` and `d` to `b`, so if you modify the values of `c` it'll be reflected in `a` as well (same goes with `d` and `b`).

However, if you do:

```
c = list(a)
```

You're basically creating a shallow copy of `a`. This means, you created a new list `c` containing the same values as those of `a`. So any mutation to `c` will not affect `a` since it's now a unique `list` instance.

Be careful though, if your list contains mutable objects they can still be mutated through the copied list. Use `copy.deepcopy` to ensure all objects are copied as new objects.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second question, "In essence, what I don't understand is how does list([0,0]) not create a list as [[0,0]]?"

The way the `list()` function works is that it takes as an argument some sort of container, specifically an iterable, and it iterates over this, putting each element in the container into a new list.

For example, a `string` is an iterable and each element is a single character:

```
>>> list('spam')
['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']
```

A `tuple` of integers is also iterable:

```
>>> list((1, 2, 3, 4))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

And of course, a list itself is iterable, so running `list()` on an existing `list` just makes a new `list` with the same contents:

```
>>> list(['oranges','spam',22.3])
['oranges', 'spam', 22.3]
```

What you can't do is pass an integer to `list()` as an integer is not iterable:

```
>>> list(42)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new list with `list([0, 0])` versus using the same list over and over.

Answer (score 0):

`list([0,0])` creates a *new* list object every time.

```
value = [0, 0]
v2 = list(value)
assert value == v2
assert id(value) != id(v2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`list(x)` means to make a new list from the *contents* of x, not to make a new one-element list containing `x` as its only element.  The contents of your `value` are two numbers (both 0), so `list(value)` makes a new list containing two zeros.

In your first example, no new lists are ever created; the same list `value` is set as the value for every key.