# How do I create a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I want to be able to enter a list of names and then for each name on that list I want to create a list of predictions on who each person thinks will win a match.

For example, I would have 
`names = [bob, bill, fred]`

Then for each name in that list I'd like to have the user enter who they think will win. So in this example I would end up with

```
bobs_predictions = []
bills_predictions = []
freds_predictions = []
```

Hopefully you understand what I mean. Basically I'd like to create a list of lists where python names the list based on a list of names...

Comment: You want a dictionary (or mapping, same thing).

Comment: thanks Reut, this worked perfectly

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a [mapping](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping):

```
predictions = {
    "bob": [...],
    "bill": [...],
    "fred": [...]
}
```

To instantiate (with empty predictions) from a list of names:

```
predictions = {name: [] for name in names}
```

To get bob's predictions:

```
bobs_predictions = predictions['bob']
```

To add a prediction to bob:

```
bobs_predictions.append(prediction)
```

Comment: @MosesKoledoye [no, you don't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516413/dict-fromkeys-all-point-to-same-list).

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski Oh sprite! Didn't think of that. Good one