# How to create a dictionary from two list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Hello guys i have two list in my code like this

```
other_concords = ['a','b','c']
leamanyi_concords = ['fruit','drink','snack']

temp_dic = {
              'a':['fruit','drink','snack'],
              'b':['fruit','drink','snack'],
              'c':['fruit','drink','snack']
            }
```

Is it possible to insert items in my temp_dic using a loop and it appears like this when i output temp_dic?

Answer (score 3):

```
temp_dic = {v: list(leamanyi_concords) for v in other_concords}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) if you don't mind your dictionary pointing to the same `list`.

```
temp_dic = dict.fromkeys(other_concords, leamanyi_concords)

# {'a': ['fruit', 'drink', 'snack'],
#  'b': ['fruit', 'drink', 'snack'],
#  'c': ['fruit', 'drink', 'snack']}
```

Comment: Generally not a good idea to use `dict.fromkeys` with some mutable arg.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516413/dict-fromkeys-all-point-to-same-list.  It has come back to bite me before

Comment: @BradSolomon - it really depends. maybe the intention is that the lists should be linked? I did add a disclaimer.