# Aggregating values from one dictionary to populate another in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a list of ~12K dictionaries. Each dictionary has the same keys: `year`, `code` and `category`.

```
L = [{"year": "2015", "code": "VU", "category": "Vulnerable"}, {"year": "2008", "code": "VU", "category": "Vulnerable"}, {"year": "2004", "code": "LC", "category": "Least Concern"}]
```

I'm trying to create a new dictionary that will have, as key, each value of `code` and, as the value to that key, a list of unique years for each `code` (I don't necessarily need the `category` key-value pair):

```
{"VU": {2008, 2015}, "LC": {2004}}
```

I created a dictionary `codes_dict` with the correct codes as keys, and empty sets as values (since I don't want duplicates, and I really only need the earliest and latest years.)

```
codes = (e['code'] for e in L)
codes_dict = dict.fromkeys(codes, set())

for e in L:
    codes_dict[e['code']].add(e['year'])
```

However, when I try to populate the values, I get every year added to every code:

```
{'VU': {'2004', '2008', '2015'}, 'LC': {'2004', '2008', '2015'}}
```

What am I missing? I tried using a `list` instead of a `set` and got the same result (with duplicates). Also using `=` instead of `add()` means only the last value is added, whereas I want the whole range.

Performance isn't really an issue, as this is just supposed to be a quick diagnostic.

**Bonus:** if there is a better way to do this in pandas, I'd love to hear it.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show the initial declaration of `codes_dict`?

Comment: @kopecs: Thanks, I just edited the question with that clarification.

Comment: Ah, they're all pointing to the same set.

Comment: Does this answer your question [dict.fromkeys all point to same list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516413/dict-fromkeys-all-point-to-same-list)? It seems to be the same root issue.

Comment: @kopecs It's useful for the analysis but I really like the defaultdict solution you gave below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, all of your values point to the same set. Try instead (using a `defaultdict`; you could instead use `get` and set each element to be a new set if it doesn't yet exist)

```py
from collections import defaultdict

L = [{"year": "2015", "code": "VU", "category": "Vulnerable"}, {"year": "2008", "code": "VU", "category": "Vulnerable"}, {"year": "2004", "code": "LC", "category": "Least Concern"}]


codes_dict = defaultdict(set)
for e in L:
    codes_dict[e['code']].add(e['year'])

print(dict(codes_dict))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dataframe using the following one-liner.

```
output = {k: list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, str) or not numpy.isnan(x), v)) for k, v in pandas.DataFrame(L).pivot(columns='code', values='year').to_dict('list').items()}
```

---

Breaking it down:

1. Load list into dataframe

```
df=pandas.DataFrame(L)
```

2. Create a pivot table where the different `codes` are columns and each cell contain the year corresponding to the code.

```
pivot_table = df.pivot(columns='code', values='year')
```

The result should look like:

```
       VU    LC
0     2008   NaN
1     2015   NaN
2     NaN    2004
```

3. Output dict of list from dataframe

```
output = pivot_table.to_dict('list')
```

The result should look like:

```
{‘VU’: [‘2008’, ‘2015’, NaN], ‘VL’: [NaN, NaN, ‘2004’]}
```

4. This is almost there. Just need to filter out the NaNs.

```
output = {k: list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, str) or not numpy.isnan(x), v)) for k, v in output.items()}
```

This uses filter function to filter out non string and NaN objects. Then uses dictionary comprehension to reconstruct the dictionary without the NaNs.

Comment: Thanks, @Tim. My pandas knowledge is still fairly beginner so this isn't easily parseable for me. If you can, a few words walking me through the expression would be very appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, that's supremely helpful. Lots of great new methods to wrap my head around.