# Difference between creating a dictionary using fromkeys and manually filling in dictionary when using set update

Tags: python

I created a dictionary using fromkeys and by manually filling it. When I want to update the values of one key, I end up updating all the values when I use the dictionary created by fromkeys. Why is this happening?

```
ex = dict.fromkeys(list(range(3)), set())
print(ex)
ex[1].update([0,1])
print(ex)

ex2 = {0: set(), 1: set(), 2: set()}
print(ex2)
ex2[1].update([0,1])
print(ex2)
```

Results

```
{0: set(), 1: set(), 2: set()}

{0: {0, 1}, 1: {0, 1}, 2: {0, 1}}

{0: set(), 1: set(), 2: set()}

{0: set(), 1: {0, 1}, 2: set()}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dict.fromkeys all point to same list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516413/dict-fromkeys-all-point-to-same-list)

Comment: You can initialize your dictionary using a comprehension: `ex = {k:{} for k in range(3)}` and then you will have independent sets for each of your keys.

Comment: Here's another similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509721/how-do-i-initialize-a-dictionary-of-empty-lists-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fromkeys()` method returns a dictionary with the specified keys and the specified value.

**Syntax**-

```
dict.fromkeys(keys, value)
```

**keys** - An iterable specifying the keys of the new dictionary.

**value** - Optional. The value for all keys.

When value for one key changes, the other values also get modified because `each element is assigned a reference to the same object` (points to the same object in the memory).