# .append() behaves differently for Python dictionaries initialized from two different methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
ky     =  ['a','b','c']

val    = 15

dict_1 = dict.fromkeys(ky,[])

dict_1['a'].append(val)

dict_2 = {'a':[],'b':[],'c':[]}

dict_2['a'].append(val)

print(dict_1)

print(dict_2)
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dict.fromkeys all point to same list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516413/dict-fromkeys-all-point-to-same-list)

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/q/11509721/4046632

Comment: @buran Thanks a lot buddy. I think your suggested question will help me to understand why I am not getting the expected result as well as alternative to meet expectation.

Comment: @Jeff Sorry for asking the question in a haphazard manner. I should've also mentioned the output where, it can be observed that 15 is appended to all the empty list rather than the specified one, i.e., 'a' : []

Comment: @mayur_m no worries, it was fairly obvious your question was "Why does .append() behave differently..." but I think it's best to be explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but given your post, I'm presuming your question is why dict_1 has the same value (15) for all its keys `a`, `b`, and `c` as the end result, right?

If so, I agree that this is unintuitive behavior at a first glance, but what is happening is that by passing `[]` (an empty list) as the second *optional* argument for the `fromkeys` method, you're populating `dict_1` dictionary with **references** to the same single empty list, hence, when you append `val` to the key `a`, all other keys are updated with the same value as well (you passed the empty list as reference. see [difference between passing by reference vs passing by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value) ).

As you noticed yourself, there are other ways to initialize a dictionary of empty lists in Python (as you did "manually" with dict_2).

In case you're interested in another "less manual" way to initialize a dictionary of empty lists in Python, you could use a `list comprehension` to do so, as in the following example:

`dict_3 = {k : [] for k in ky}`

That would initialize `dict_3` with empty lists (passed by value), thus, keys `b` and `c` would be unaffected when you append `val` to the key `a`.

I hope that helps to clarify your example. Kind regards.

Comment: very well explained the issue and thank you for the alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

they are all using the same ref when you use `dict.fromkeys()` A change to one is a change to all since they are the same object

You could use a dict comprehension instead of append:

```
keys = ['a','b','c']
value = [0, 0]
{key: list(value) for key in keys}
{'a': [0, 0], 'b': [0, 0], 'c': [0, 0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `dict_1 = dict.fromkeys(ky,[])`, all keys are mapped to the same (empty) array.

So whenever you change **the contents** of that array, each one of these keys will (still) point to the same array containing these new contents.

Answer (score 0):

`dict_1 = dict.fromkeys(ky,[])` creates a single list and then calls `fromkeys`. That one list is used for the value paired with each key. One list referenced through all of the keys.

If you want unique lists, use a dictionary comprehension

```
dict_3 = {k:[] for k in ky}
```

Here, `k:[]` is evaluated for each key and a new list is created for each value.